# Wpf expander in listview

Tags: c#, wpf

I have list view with expander in it. Is it possible to make expanding like on screen?
[image]

```
 <Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Expander Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="0" Margin="41.343,0,-27,0">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Label Content="First Element"/>
                                <Label Content="Second Element"/>
                                <Label Content="Third Element"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Test"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Test"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="220.35"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Content="15.37"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Content="4.54"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" Content="00:04:01"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I tried to place "First Element","Second Element","Third eletment" in Grid and change its expanding size, but xaml does not allow to place left border of grid to the left of expander left border.

Comment: use the stackpanel Orientation="Horizontal" property

Comment: You want Expander be expanded horizontally under your labels? What is the purpose of the layout - it may lead to more precise answers.

Comment: To dytori Yes i want Expander be expanded horizontally under labels. The purpos is show some additional information maybe like price with discount under real price.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work as a basis, you will need to tweak the rest to fit your specific requirements, but what i did is to add an additional row so your expander can sit in that row and expand left by rowspaning the entire length of the grid columns.

```
<Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Expander ExpandDirection="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="1" Margin="41.343,0,-27,0">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="First Element"/>
                                <Label Content="Second Element"/>
                                <Label Content="Third Element"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Test"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Test"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="220.35"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Content="15.37"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Content="4.54"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" Content="00:04:01"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry but Expander button should be in the Grid.Row="0". Its very important.

Comment: then change this line to the following 
`<Expander ExpandDirection="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="0" Margin="41.343,0,-27,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">`
and set the height of row 0 so the values are close enough.